# Excel exclude date range work hour calculation for non workdays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to exclude this calculation for Saturdays and Sundays or have 0 returned for week-ends?

```
=IF(AND(DATE($L$1,10,1)>=A9,DATE($L$1,6,17)<=A9),6,8.75)
```

This formula calculates the hours to be worked against a date range being 6 hours for summer schedule (from 16 June to 30 September) and the remaining days returns a value of 8.75 hours. $L$1 returns the year (value of cell **L1** e.g. 2016).

I am aware of the WORKDAY function, but I cannot get the formula to work.

What I am after is to have a 0 returned for any given Saturday or Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `WORKDAY` function. Simply check if `WEEKDAY` of the date is not Saturday or Sunday.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A9,2)>5,0,IF(AND(DATE($L$1,10,1)>=A9,DATE($L$1,6,17)<=A9),6,8.75))
```

To check if the date in `A9` is or is not a holiday, `WORKDAY`  is the wrong approach since `WORKDAY` is thought to calculate the **date** of the workday not to check if a given date **is** a workday.

We can use `COUNTIF` to check if the date in `A9` is in a range with holidays.

Example: holidays dates are in `$F$2:$F$4`

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A9,2)>5,COUNTIF($F$2:$F$4,A9)>0),0,IF(AND(DATE($L$1,10,1)>=A9,DATE($L$1,6,17)<=A9),6,8.75))
```

Comment: Axel, thanks for the prompt guidance but how can I set the WEEKDAY to an already existing date. In my time sheet the date is set in cell A8 and the day is set in B8 with the =TEXT(A8,"dddd")

Comment: Your given formula checks if the date in `A9` is in summer or not. So I've assumed the date being in `A9`. So I dont understand your comment.

Comment: Thanks Axel, I had a typo arranged A9 to A8 and the formula worked. I want to ask if there is a way to add public holidays that fall on work days to the WEEKDAY formula just like WORKDAY